# How to multiply two shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Is it possible to multiply two shapefiles without creating two rasters?
I have a first shapefile representing the exposure of an object to a landslide phenomenon and a second shapefile indicating the landslide hazard. The result must be a polygonal shapefile that represents the risk.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can probably just intersect the two datasets, and multiply the two fields of interest in a newly created field.

Comment: With vector layers, this operation is called intersection, the result will be a vector layer with polygons of the first shapefile clipped by the polygons of the second one. All attributes of the two shapefiles will be there then create a new field and apply the formula : `"layer1.field1" * "layer2.field2"`.